# how can i return to the previous activity according to the path i followed in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, back

In my Android project I have Activities A,B,C,D. I set in Manifest that A is parent of B. B is parent of C and C is parent of D. If i go: A->B->C->D and press back in Action Bar everything works fine.
I go: A->C->D->B. If i press back in action bar of B, it takes me to A and not to activity D.
Any ideas what to do?

Comment: You need to understand task and backstack how activity is added to the stack and popped out http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.

Comment: By back in this scenario, do you mean 'Home as up'? The "back" button in the top left of the screen? and not the hardware back button

Comment: tell where you want to go in the back

Comment: If you just want to go back to the previous activity in the history stack, do not set parents in the manifest.

Comment: yes i want just to go the previous activity in the history stack. Lets say i remove parents from the manifest, what should i do next? I want android.R.id.home to do the same action as the back button in emulator

Comment: i want the arrow back on the action bar. If i dont declare the parents in the manifest then there is no back arrow

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the up navigation to behave like the back button. So if you tap the back arrow on the action bar you get back to the last opened activity, right? Actually that is not how android apps are supposed to work: Tapping the up navigation should bring you higher in the hierarchy defined by the parent tags. Tapping the back button should bring you to the last activity on the back stack.

Comment: thnx again for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you confuse back and up navigation: Back navigation gets you to the last activity on the back stack,
up navigation gets you the navigation that you have defined as the parent activity:

Example:
A is the parent of B and B is the parent of C. (A -> B -> C)
You go from A -> C - > B

If you use the back button, you will got back to the activity that was open before the current activity. So you will land at C.
If you use the up navigation (by tapping the app icon on the upper left of the screen) you will go to the parent activity. In our case B.

Hope this helps and ask if you have further questions.

EDIT:
If you want the up button behave like the back button you could do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        startIntent(new Intent(this, yourParentClass.class));
        return true;
    }
}
```

This way you would start a new activity.